# Selecionar opção do select de acordo com parâmetro da url

Tags: javascript, jquery, loop, filter, selected-option

eu tenho o script abaixo que pega um parâmetro da URL(se tiver), procura em todos os selects da página e seleciona a opção com o mesmo valor(mesmo valor do parâmetro). Se não tiver um parâmetro na URL, ele seleciona a primeira opção do select. Até aqui, blz!
Eu preciso que se tiver um parâmetro na URL ele procure em todos os selects da página e se encontrar ele seleciona e se caso não exista no PRÓXIMO select, ele marque a primeira opção.

```
if (hash !== undefined) {
$('.kit-list').each(function (i) {
    $('.kit-list:eq(' + i + ') select option').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == hash.size.replace('%20', ' ');
    }).prop("selected", true);
    $('.kit-list:eq(' + i + ') select').change();
});
} else {
$('.kit-list').each(function (i) {
    $('.kit-list:eq(' + i + ') select').find('option').eq(1).attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('.kit-list:eq(' + i + ') select').change();
});
}
```

Comment: Exemplo do HTML? Exemplo de valores que podem estar no hash?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi meu problema da seguinte forma(não sei se é a melhor mas funcionou):

```
if (hash !== undefined) {
    $('.kit-list').each(function (i) {
        if ($('.kit-list:eq(' + i + ') #espec_0_opcao_0 option[value=' + hash.size.replace('%20', ' ') + ']').length > 0) {
            $('.kit-list:eq(' + i + ') #espec_0_opcao_0 option').filter(function () {
                return $(this).text() == hash.size.replace('%20', ' ');
            }).prop("selected", true);
            $('.kit-list:eq(' + i + ') #espec_0_opcao_0').change();
            console.log('sim')
        } else {
            console.log('nao')
            $('.kit-list:eq(' + i + ') #espec_0_opcao_0').find('option').eq(1).attr('selected', 'selected');
            $('.kit-list:eq(' + i + ') #espec_0_opcao_0').change();
        }

    });
} else {
    $('.kit-list').each(function (i) {
        $('.kit-list:eq(' + i + ') select').find('option').eq(1).attr('selected', 'selected');
        $('.kit-list:eq(' + i + ') select').change();
    });
}
```